# Why does my Broadcast Receiver receive 4 broadcasts on PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, android-gps

I cannot wrap my head around this strange problem. What I am basically trying to do is that, I am registering a broadcast receiver that listens to whether the user turned on or off the GPS, and then accordingly does something. Strangely, when the user changes the GPS state, the broadcast receiver gets triggered not once, but for 4 times back to back! What is the reason behind it? Is there a better way?

The receiver is named ***'gpsStateReceiver'***

**Here is the code for the Activity:**

```
package com.coffeetech.birdsight;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.Projection;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

public class BirdsEyeView extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    final int LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    final int REQUEST_GET_PERMISSION = 2;
    final float ZOOM_DEFAULT = 17f;
    final int INTERVAL = 1000;
    final String TAG = "CHECK THIS MESSAGE: ";
    //final float SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT = 0.3f;
    boolean isGpsOn = false;
    boolean gpsListenerTriggeredAlready = false;
    //----------------------

    LocationSettingsRequest locationSettingsRequest;
    LocationRequest locationRequest;
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    Marker myMarker;
    LatLng newLatLng;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    Location lastKnownLocation;
    UiSettings googleMapSettings;
    LocationCallback locationCallback;
    MarkerOptions markerOptions;
    BroadcastReceiver gpsStateReceiver;
    IntentFilter gpsStateFilter;
    //-----------------------------------------

    FloatingActionButton show_my_location_button;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class)
        .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        try{
            stopGettingUserLocations();
            unregisterReceiver(gpsStateReceiver);
        }catch (Exception e){}
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_birds_eye_view);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        show_my_location_button = findViewById(R.id.show_my_location_button_birds_eyeview);

        //GPS STATE RECEIVER
        //TODO
        gpsStateFilter = new IntentFilter();
        gpsStateFilter.addAction(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        gpsStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { //THIS GETS TRIGGERED 4 TIMES
                    Log.e(TAG, "TRIGGERED!");
                if(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())){
                        int mode = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(),
                                Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE,Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF);
                        if(mode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF){
                            //ON GPS TURNED ON
                            isGpsOn = true;
                            startGettingUserLocations();
                        }else{
                            isGpsOn = false;
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Cannot find location without GPS",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            stopGettingUserLocations();
                            //ON GPS TURNED OFF
                        }
                    }

            }
        };
        registerReceiver(gpsStateReceiver,gpsStateFilter);

        //gets handle to map
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(BirdsEyeView.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
        googleMapSettings = googleMap.getUiSettings();

        //MAP UI SETTINGS
        googleMapSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        googleMapSettings.setCompassEnabled(false);

        //MY MARKER SETTINGS
        markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.draggable(false);
        markerOptions.alpha(0.75f);
        //TODO: markerOptions.icon()

        int mode = Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF;
        try {
            mode = Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
        } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {}

        if(mode == Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF){
            //If gps was off, it is turned on
            turnOnGps();
        }else{
            //gps is already on
            startGettingUserLocations();
        }


        show_my_location_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newLatLng,ZOOM_DEFAULT));
            }
        });
    }

    //------------------------------------------
    //---------UTILITY FUNCTIONS BELOW----------
    //----------------------------------------

   protected void turnOnGps(){
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL).setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationSettingsRequest = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest).build();
        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this).checkLocationSettings(locationSettingsRequest);

        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                //GPS IS ON
                //startGettingUserLocations();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                if(e instanceof ResolvableApiException){
                    ResolvableApiException resolvableApiException = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                    try {
                        resolvableApiException.startResolutionForResult(BirdsEyeView.this,REQUEST_GET_PERMISSION);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
   }

    protected void animateMarker(final Marker marker, final LatLng newPosition,
                                 final boolean hideMarker) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        Projection proj = googleMap.getProjection();
        Point startPoint = proj.toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());
        final LatLng startLatLng = proj.fromScreenLocation(startPoint);
        final long duration = 500;

        final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
                        / duration);
                double lng = t * newPosition.longitude + (1 - t)
                        * startLatLng.longitude;
                double lat = t * newPosition.latitude + (1 - t)
                        * startLatLng.latitude;
                marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));

                if (t < 1.0) {
                    // Post again 16ms later.
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
                } else {
                    if (hideMarker) {
                        marker.setVisible(false);
                    } else {
                        marker.setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected void stopGettingUserLocations(){
        fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
        gpsListenerTriggeredAlready = false;
    }

    protected void startGettingUserLocations() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Locating",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Locating.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Locating..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Locating...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        locationCallback = new LocationCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                //TODO: GET LOCATION UPDATES HERE
                lastKnownLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                newLatLng = new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());

                if(myMarker == null){
                    myMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions.position(newLatLng));
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newLatLng,ZOOM_DEFAULT));
                }else{
                    animateMarker(myMarker,newLatLng,false);
                }
            }
        };

        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL).setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,locationCallback,Looper.getMainLooper());

        gpsListenerTriggeredAlready = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: "when the user changes the GPS state" -- my guess is that you are not changing the "GPS state", but rather are enabling or disabling locations. There are multiple location providers, and you are enabling or disabling all of them.

Comment: @CommonsWare So how do I rewrite it, so that when the user turns the Location on or off, the receiver only gets triggered once? Also, what are the 4 providers? WiFi, Cell network, GPS, and Internet?

Comment: "So how do I rewrite it, so that when the user turns the Location on or off, the receiver only gets triggered once?" -- AFAIK, that is not an option. "what are the 4 providers?" -- three should be GPS, network, and passive. If you are running on Android 10+, look at the `EXTRA_PROVIDER_NAME` extra on the `Intent` to see what particular provider the broadcast is for. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION) for more.

Comment: @CommonsWare Umm well, is there a workaround, or maybe a better way?

Comment: The simplest thing is to have your code be able to cope with multiple broadcasts. Alternatively, do not use that broadcast, but instead do something else. For example, you may be able to register a `ContentObserver` for `Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE` [using `getUriFor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#getUriFor(java.lang.String)).

Comment: @CommonsWare Alright thanks. I'll look into it.